# How to drop selected multiple indexes for a collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to drop multiple selected indexes by name using query in mongodb

I tried using dropIndex to drop multiple indexes.But this is deleting only first index i.e,index_1

> db.getCollection('test').dropIndex( "index_1", "index_2" )

should delete index_1 and index_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.collection.dropIndexes()

Drops all indexes other than the required index on the _id field.

The db.collection.dropIndex() method takes the following parameter:

index   (string or document)

Specifies the index to drop. You can specify the index either by the index name or by the index specification document.

So, it means you can not specify two indexes. To delete two indexes call db.collection.dropIndex() twice.

To obtain a list of documents that identify and describe the existing indexes on the collection use

db.collection.getIndexes()